# Unzip files with Apache Camel?

Tags: file, apache-camel, unzip

How I can extract files (one or more than one) from a zip file with Apache Camel? Is it possible?

I'm trying this

```
from("file:/home/myinputzip?noop=true&delay=5000&moveFailed=error")
  .split(new ZipSplitter())
    .streaming().convertBodyTo(String.class)      
  .to("file:/home/myinputzip")
.end();
```

When I start the application, the file is extracted from zip, but camel throws an exception and the file is moved to error folder:

> ERROR: org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed
>   delivery for (MessageId: ID-ubuntu-35217-1377806407437-0-5 on
>   ExchangeId: ID-ubuntu-35217-1377806407437-0-7). Exhausted after
>   delivery attempt: 1 caught:
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException:
>   Cannot write null body to file:
>   /home/myinputzip/aVIII_crrpfp201304.cap
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException:
>   Cannot write null body to file:
>   /home/myinputzip/aVIII_crrpfp201304.cap at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.FileOperations.storeFile(FileOperations.java:194)
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.writeFile(GenericFileProducer.java:257)
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.processExchange(GenericFileProducer.java:159)
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileProducer.process(GenericFileProducer.java:80)
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298)
>   at
>   org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117)

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Is this related to this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-6679 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved as follows

```
from("file:/home/myinputzip?noop=true&delay=5000&moveFailed=error")
  .split(new ZipSplitter())
    .streaming().convertBodyTo(String.class) 
        .choice()
            .when(body().isNotNull())
                .to("file:/home/myinputzip")
        .end()
.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that your route should work, however, have you tried something like this:

```
from("file:/home/myinputzip?noop=true&delay=5000&moveFailed=error")
  .unmarshal().zip()
  .split(body(Iterable.class))
    .streaming().convertBodyTo(String.class)      
  .to("file:/home/myinputzip")
.end();
```

I have take this example from http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/zip-file-best-practices-td5713437.html

I hope this works for you!

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't works... When I deploy the server throws a exception 
`ERROR: org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-ubuntu-48866-1377893653015-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-ubuntu-48866-1377893653015-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check
java.util.zip.ZipException: incorrect header check
 at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:164)`

Comment: From the example link, looks like this route requires the zipped data to have been loaded into the route - it doesn't handle processing files.