# Apache Camel (JBoss Fuse) - how to unzip a file from a MQ route?

Tags: java, apache-camel, unzip, dataformat, jbossfuse

I am receiving `zipped`data  on a camel route, running in JBoss Fuse (also known as Fuse ESB).

Having added some log statements, I can see that the incoming data is Bytes (and it looks all scrambled, so I am pretty sure it is zipped data).

However the `unmarshall().zip()` part of my camel route doesn't unzip the data to text - I still have bytes (and they still look scrambled.

```
from("webspheremq:topic:SNAPSHOTS")
    .log("before unzip, body class is: ${body.class}")   // bytes in...
    .unmarshall().zip()
    .log("after unzip, body class is: ${body.class}")   // still bytes! not good.
```

I am obviously doing something wrong here.

So I had a look at this question: [Unzip files with Apache Camel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520045/unzip-files-with-apache-camel)

But unfortunately `camel-zipfile` does not seem available to me in the JBoss Fuse environment I am working in, so I couldn't use `ZipSplitter()`.

Can someone please tell me how to `unzip` data in an Apache Camel route in JBoss Fuse?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Nice to see other Australians using fuse esb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it was quite simple:

```
from("xyz")
    .unmarshal(new ZipDataFormat())
    .convertBodyTo(String.class)
```

Hope this helps.